# Android: Update UI periodically from a thread

Tags: android

Guess that I have a TextView that I want to update it in some situations. I want to have a thread that every one or two seconds checks the circumstances and updates TextView's text if necessary. 
Any Idea?

Comment: A thread may be overkill unless there's some blocking operation associated with it.  A Handler in conjunction with `postDelayed(runnable, 2000)` may be suitable for your needs.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Handler, in your GUI:

```
Handler hnd = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if ( msg.what == 101 ) {
           //update textview
        }
    }
}
```

pass hnd to your thread, and in your thread do:

```
Message m = new Message();
m.what = 101;
hnd.sendMessage(m);
```

this assumes that in your separate thread you are doing some work that needs reporting to GUI thread, you can also send text messages

Comment: There's one IMPORTANT typo in your answer: the method should be handleMessage(without the R). I tried editing your answer but they rejected the edits. Check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 4):

I do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private Handler  hUpdate;
  private Runnable rUpdate;

  public MyClass() { // Constructor
    hUpdate = new Handler();
    rUpdate = new Runnable() {
      // Do your GUI updates here
    };

    Thread tUpdate = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        while(true) {
          hUpdate.post(rUpdate);
          sleep(500);
        }
      }
    }
    tUpdate.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use an handler to update view from another thread. With postDelayed you can set a delay. see the doc:

[handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)